# Rails 4 multi table join with data from all tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I think this is simple but I'm just not getting it.  I need to join 3 tables  and have rails return values from all 3.  I have done a join but rails only returns values from 1 table.  I think I just don't know the syntax

Here is my controller method

```
@previous_results = Test.joins(:run, :detail).where("runs.name = ? AND tests.name = ?", @run.name, @test.name).last(1000)
```

That does do a join here is the sql from it

```
SELECT  `tests`.* FROM `tests` INNER JOIN `runs` ON `runs`.`id` = `tests`.`run_id` INNER JOIN `details` ON `details`.`test_id` = `tests`.`id` 
WHERE (runs.name = 'SNMSubscriberSpecificTemplatesFeedsTest' AND tests.name = 'testSitePrefixFalseForNTINSequentialList')  ORDER BY `tests`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1000
```

all I need to do is return values from the details table also.  I want 2 column values from details essentially instead of doing test .* I was test.id, test.name, detail.text, detail.message    as my return

Int active record how do I tell it to not just return test table data but also include columns in details

This query in SQL does what I want I need to know how to active record it

```
SELECT  `tests`.*, `details`.`detail_text`, `details`.`detail_error`
FROM `tests` 
INNER JOIN `runs` ON `runs`.`id` = `tests`.`run_id` 
INNER JOIN `details`   ON `tests`.`id` = `details`.`id`
WHERE (runs.name = 'SNMSubscriberSpecificTemplatesFeedsTest' AND tests.name = 'testSitePrefixFalseForNTINSequentialList')
ORDER BY `tests`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@tests = Test
  .select('tests.*', 'details.detail_text', 'details.detail_error')
  .joins(:run, :detail)
  .where(
    runs: { name: 'SNMSubscriberSpecificTemplatesFeedsTest' },
    tests: { name: 'testSitePrefixFalseForNTINSequentialList' }
  )
  .limit(1000)
  .order(id: :desc)
```

your views would look like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Test ID</th>
    <th>Test Detail's Detail Text</th>
    <th>Test Detail's Detail Error</th>
  </tr>
  <% @tests.each do |test| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= test.id %></td>
      <td><%= test.detail_text %></td>
      <td><%= test.detail_error %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

### Recommendation:

- do not use `select()` explicitly to fetch the "associated values", but instead access them directly through the objects, like below

  ```
  @tests = Test
    .joins(:run, :detail).includes(:detail)
    .where(
      runs: { name: 'SNMSubscriberSpecificTemplatesFeedsTest' },
      tests: { name: 'testSitePrefixFalseForNTINSequentialList' }
    )
    .limit(1000)
    .order(id: :desc)
  ```

  your views would look something like:

  ```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Test ID</th>
      <th>Test Detail's Detail Text</th>
      <th>Test Detail's Detail Error</th>
    </tr>
    <% @tests.each do |test| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= test.id %></td>
        <td><%= test.detail.detail_text %></td>
        <td><%= test.detail.detal_error %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: previous_results = Test.joins(:run, :detail).where("runs.name = ? AND tests.name = ?", @run.name, @test.name).last(1000)   Will return lots of rows I want each of those rows to include info from the details table so I'm not sure what you propose will work.  My test table holds lots of pass fail info for a test the details table has test.id as a secondary key and it hold the actual details of the failure.  so I want to get the info from test and add the details for that test.id.  If that makes sense.  Then I load all that into a data table for display

Comment: I updated my answer to "include detail" values, so that it will only have one query instead of multiple ones when loading `details` table values. Is this what you want?

Comment: maybe I am just not getting this I apologize. my view get the previous_results var and loops through it in a table.  I need that var to include data from both tables.  so (pseudo code)  if "Test" name, id  and details "test id, error msg, error text"   I want previous_results to have a list of test name, test id, detail.error msg, detail.error text

Comment: I just updated my answer to include a "sample" view code that renders a table (as you needed)